# Is it true that $ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h, y_0 + h) - f(x_0 + h, y_0)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)?$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Let $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that both partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at $(x_0,y_0)$.

> Is is true that
>
> $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h, y_0 + h) - f(x_0 + h, y_0)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)?$$

I believe that this statement is true if we know that $f$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $(x_0, y_0)$, for then the mean value theorem tells us that

$$\frac{f(x_0 + h, y_0 + h) - f(x_0 + h, y_0)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0+ h, \tilde{y}) $$

for some $\tilde{y}$ between $y_0$ and $y_0 + h$, and this will converge to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)$ as $h \to 0$. But if $f$ is not $C^1$ then we don't have as much to work with. It seems that it may not be true in this case and we need to find a counterexample.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the $h$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - I wasn't able to figure out what the right statement should be using the the vector $(h_1, h_2)$, so I've reduced things to just the parameter $h$.

Comment: It probably should have been $\|(h_1,h_2)\|$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Not sure why you say this.

Comment: @zhw. see the revision history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $f(x,y) = \min (|x|,|y|).$ Then $f$ is continuous everywhere. Take $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0).$ Then the partial derivatives of $f$ are $0$ at $(0,0).$ But

$$\frac{f(0+h,0+h) - f(h,0)}{h} = \frac{|h|-0}{h},$$

which has no limit as $h\to 0.$